# avconv option for scale causes "Invalid frame size" error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, avconv

I use avconv to get a preview image of a video clip. The command is

`avconv -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 100x100 cover.jpeg`

It works but I would like to have correct dimensions of the output jpeg. For example to be the half size of the input video. So I execute

`avconv -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 'iw/2:ih/2' cover.jpeg`

but this just causes `Invalid frame size: iw/2:ih/2` error. How should I pass advanced scale options to avconv in command line?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "scale=iw/2:ih/2" cover.jpeg
```